# In Hyperledger Fabric v2.1, in the test-network repo sample - Error in channel creation

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I'm trying to create a channel from the test-network sample of Hyperledger Fabric v2.1. I have installed all the latest fabric binaries & Docker images. The channel-artifacts, 2 peers and a ordering node were successfully created.

However, the command `./network.sh createChannel` gives the following error.

> Error: failed to create deliver client for orderer: failed to load config for OrdererClient: unable to load orderer.tls.rootcert.file: open /home/fabric/HLF/fabric-sample: no such file or directory
>   !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe CreateChannel is roughly 5 steps.

1. Generate a CreateChannel Transaction
2. Generate an Anchor peer transaction
3. Create the channel with the genesis block
4. Join the peers to the channel and
5. Update one peer in each organization to Anchor peer.

Any chance you can share the output of `./network.sh createChannel`, I'd like to see how far you got before you ran into this error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by removing the spaces from name of parent directory in which the "fabric-samples" repo were installed. This was the final output was:

2020-05-14 16:56:04.064 IST [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2020-05-14 16:56:04.130 IST [channelCmd] update -> INFO 002 Successfully submitted channel update
===================== Anchor peers updated for org 'Org2MSP' on channel 'mychannel' =====================

========= Channel successfully joined ===========

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, The problem is with the directory fabric-samples kindly re-download the binaries and try again.

Download using curl via:

`curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/release-2.1/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s -- 2.1.0 1.5.2`

Hope this helps, otherwise see the directory structures and path exports.